# Android Eclipse Helios

Tags: android, eclipse, helios

I am running Eclipse Indigo with android development on MacBook Pro with a 2.4ghz intel core 2 duo processor and 4gb of RAM. I used to run it on an older version of eclipse supporting up to the google level 8 api and it ran just fine using Helios (I am using the AVD emulator) ...lately I have been trying develop new projects and re run old projects and it gets stuck at launching the application at about 27%, and then just gets locked up. I am now running under Indigo supporting up to the newest api level....I ran TOP command and sometimes eclipse uses 104% of the %CPU. I am not running any other programs during this time. Do you guys think its time I upgrade to 8 gigs of ram?

Comment: I would delete Eclipse, the Android SDK, everything, and start with a fresh clean install of the lastest bits.  Upgrading Eclipse from Helios to Indigo broke a bunch of Android stuff for me.

Comment: Are you running now under Helios or Indigo?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Indigo and face no such problem. The only issue I have is running AVD for 4.0 which sometimes doesnot behave well and on top it is damn slow. My system is 3 years old, with Core 2 Duo, 4GB ram.